# Is it possible to force all Azure AD B2C MFA to be Auto Dial Phone Call. Also Hide the Call me Button

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

How we can achieves this via custom policies into azure b2c mfa.
I am trying to hide the call me button in case of auto dial.

Answer (score 0):

The following in the phonefactor technical profile's metadata section will force `Call Me` option only.

```xml
<Item Key="setting.authenticationMode">phone</Item>
```

To do auto dial, hide the button using CSS, and use JavaScript to auto click the button.